# What are these conics invariant under linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, conic-sections

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
be a matrix with determinant $1$. Then one can see that the conic given by the equation
$$Q(x,y)=cx^2+(d-a)xy-by^2=C,\quad C\geq 0$$
is invariant under multiplication by $A$.

This comes from the fact that if
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\ -a&-b\end{pmatrix}$$
then $Q(v)=v^TMv$ and $A^TMA=M$.

I didn't succeed in finding resources on the subject. Does anyone know more on this subject and can point me to something of interest?